# when moving from server, I get error when calling data: Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'session_id' in 'field list'

Tags: database-migrations

I moved a site from one server to the other.
Before that, I imported a backup. Appearently there is something wrong now.
Most of the tnings seem normal, but I get this on the site, and when I try to login the CP.
This is bad.

How could I repair this?

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'session_id' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `exp_security_hashes` (`date`, `hash`, `session_id`) VALUES (xxlotxxofxxcharactersxx)

Filename: core/EE_Security.php

Line Number: 118
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is here:
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/4910/1615

he says
Run the following SQL on your database;

```
ALTER TABLE  `exp_security_hashes` ADD  `session_id` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' AFTER  `date`
```

This will create the necessary column.

And i am thankful having found this!